# Como remover espaços no início e fim de uma saída XLS

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou com o código abaixo, para ele abrir uma planilha em `XLS` e me mostrar o cabeçalho. porem gostaria que os espaços a esquerda e direita fossem removido e os internos fossem substituídos por underline
existe alguma função no `xlrd` que faça isso?

```
   import xlrd

    def xlread(arq_xls):

        xls = xlrd.open_workbook(arq_xls)
        # Pega a primeira planilha do arquivo
        plan = xls.sheets()[0]

        # Para i de zero ao numero de linhas da planilha
        for i in xrange(plan.nrows):
            # Le os valores nas linhas da planilha
            yield plan.row_values(0)

    for linha in xlread("teste.xls"):
        print linha
```

Exemplo de Saida;

```
[u'Cod.Lab.', u'Laudo', u'Cliente', u'Fazenda', u'Talh\xe3o', u'Profundidade', u'Descri\xe7\xe3o', u' pH          ', u'pH', u' pH           ', u'CE', u'MO ', u'P resina', u'S-SO4', u'K (res)', u'Na', u'Ca', u'Mg', u'Al'
```

Como pode ver aonde tem ~ fica desconfigurado e no "pH" existem vários espaços.

Comment: Oi Guilherme. Consegue postar um exemplo da saída que você está recebendo e a saída que você quer?

Comment: editei. Como eu quero, seria tudo num mesmo formato, lowcase, sem acento e espaços.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para retirar os espaços em branco antes e depois do texto, você pode usar o `.strip()`.

Para imprimir os caracteres especiais, você pode por o `.encode('utf-8')`.

Para colocar tudo em *lower case*, coloque um `.lower()` no final da sentença toda.

Para trocar os vários espaços no meio da string por um único `_`, você pode fazer um `.split()` para separar todas as palavras dentro da string e depois juntá-las com o `"_".join()`.

Juntando os quatro ficaria assim:

```
print "_".join(celula.encode('utf-8').strip().lower().split())
```

Sendo que `celula` é uma iteração de cada elemento de `linha`.

Além do mais você tem um erro de lógica nesse trecho:

```
yield plan.row_values(0)
```

Onde ao invés de `0` deveria ser `i`.

Colocando tudo de volta no seu código ficaria assim:

```
import xlrd


def xlread(arq_xls):

    xls = xlrd.open_workbook(arq_xls)
    # Pega a primeira planilha do arquivo
    plan = xls.sheets()[0]

    # Para i de zero ao numero de linhas da planilha
    for i in xrange(plan.nrows):
        # Le os valores nas linhas da planilha
        yield plan.row_values(i)

for linha in xlread("teste.xlsx"):
    for celula in linha:
        print "_".join(celula.encode('utf-8').strip().lower().split())
```

Comment: Muito bacana, resolveu uma boa parte do problema. Porem como descrevi no texto (erro meu talvez), para colocar tudo como lowercase e também retirar os espaços de dentro...talvez substituir por underline

Comment: Para colocar em lowercase é só por um `.lower()` depois de strip. Sobre os espaços no meio da frase você tem que decidir, é pra tirar ou pra por `_`? Além do mais, seria bom se você editasse sua pergunta, pois essa parte ficou _escondida_ nos comentários.

Comment: acho que o ideal seria colocar um _

Comment: ok, editando a resposta

Comment: Perfeito Math .

Answer (score 0):

Creio que os espaços podem ser facilmente removido da seguinte forma:

```
for linha in xlread("teste.xls"):
    for item in linha:
        print item.strip()
```

Quanto aos caracteres especiais acho que deves deixar dessa forma, quando estes forem lidos da lista deverão voltar ao seu formato original.

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'..ocorreu o seguinte erro.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima enganei-me ao escrever o código. Já está corrigido

Comment: Isso resolveu a questão do espaços no começo, porem no centro ou até mesmo as letras maiúsculas. Mas muito Obrigado.